# Error with NetworkOnMainThread exception

Tags: android, database, post

I want to make post to the remote db from my device, but i've got NetworkOnMainThread except, how can I solve this task ? Also I need simple example how to post data to remote db.

```
ib_wyslij.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                sendAccelerationData(zam);

            }
    });



    private void sendAccelerationData(Zamowienie zam)
    {

        //Add data to be send.
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Zam_suma", Float.toString(zam.getSuma())));

        this.sendData(nameValuePairs);
    }

private void sendData(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data){

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.kupa.pl/1.php");
            httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
                //Could do something better with response.
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
        }  
    }
```

Comment: o.o..do your network stuff in a separate thread....

Comment: Have you even bothered to google the exception or scan through a few questions on SO before posting this ? Down-voted for lack of basic research ...

Comment: in this example he shows how to SEND data! i need an example where he POST data

Comment: does not matter SEND or POST

Answer (score 2):

As the exception is telling you - what is wrong is you are doing network activity on the main thread. Put it into the background asynchronously. For this case an AsyncTask will work perfectly.

```
  private void sendAccelerationData(final Zamowienie zam) {

      new AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>() {

          public void doInBackground(...) {

                //Add data to be send.
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Zam_suma", Float.toString(zam.getSuma())));

                MyActivityClass.this.sendData(nameValuePairs);

          }

      }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make network operations in your main UI, because that would block your program execution with a very disgusting experience for your users. For this, you have to separate network operations inside a `Thread`, or even better, an `AsyncTask` if you're just starting with the thread world.

This is the structure you would use:

```
final class MyNetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Void> {
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute(final Void param) {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(final URL... args) {
    ...
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(final Void param) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Even the method names are very self explanatory. When you define your AsyncTask, and call `.execute(url_object)` on it, the first called method will be `.onPreExecute()`, there you may initialize variables and prepare everything for the network operation you want to do. The *hard* part of your network operation should be done inside `doInBackground()`. There you connect, do the data transfer and disconnect from the host. Finally, `onPostExecute()` is called: Once you're done, you can process here your results (transfer it to the main Activity, show a Dialog, etc.).

For more on AsyncTasks (and know what does those parameters mean) I strongly recommend reading the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

A very good example might be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html).

Answer (score -3):

Add this in your `onCreate()`

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
```

ADD this to Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Better use thread or asynctask for network tasks...

Comment: This doesn't answer this question at all. If he had a permissions error the log would say that, not NetworkOnMainThread

Comment: ya also I have written  "Better use thread or asynctask for network tasks..."

Comment: Terrible advice to propose *permitAll*, especially for beginners...